# Nuxt/Sanity/Netlify SSR not showing up to date data

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, netlify, nuxt3, sanity

I’m using Nuxt 3 with Sanity and hosted on Netlify and have always ran npm run generate to serve SSG which requires a redeploy after content/data changes. This has always generally worked fine. However recently I had to serve a build as SSR using npm run build.

So with SSR, using npm run build, if I make a change on Sanity it should be affected on the production site almost immediately, right? Each page visit should have the most up to date content (no need for a redeploy).

I have useCdn set to false in my nuxt.config.js for Sanity and I query my data using the composable useSanityQuery.

It’s bugging me out because I thought I maybe just didn’t understand SSR (as it’s my first site as SSR rather than SSG) and it can’t be Sanity as locally it’s correct and redeploying it fixes it.

Can anyone advise whether I’m completely misunderstanding SSR npm run build or should the production site be showing live changes within a reasonable timeframe? The changes never come through.

Attached is what Netlify have responded with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The idea is correct, it all comes down to how Sanity's data is fetched. If it's getting the data in some SSG-only (generate) kind of place or if it's calling an API endpoint. Check your code to find out where Sanity is called, update some data on Sanity and see if it's updated locally, local dev server or SSR in production is pretty much the same idea in terms of data fetching.

Comment: I’ve added a reply from Netlify to the original question… but I’m not sure they’re correct? It currently works locally but not in production using npm run build

Comment: True, you need to remove the pre-render part if you do not make it static. Goes back to the question of where/how you fetch data from Sanity. Also, does it work locally if you build it and run it locally? Finally, last time I checked Netlify was not doing SSR, only static stuff. If you want SSR, you need a Node-like server to serve it, so that every request reaches the server and spits the result. Platforms like Render, Heroku etc...might do that for you if you truly need a heavy duty SSR hosting platform. But I might be wrong and maybe nowadays Netlify has SSR? Need to double-check that one.